# How to change main menu icons in Android app

Tags: android, menu

I had an android app developed and I would like to change the main menu icons. I looked in android studio, but on the preview screen the icons do not appear, yet on the app they do. I have searched through the source folders but cannot find any of the icon images.

Here is the screen of android studio with menu invisible.
http://postimg.org/image/4zyeaxjed/

Here is screenshot of app working.
http://postimg.org/image/gvs0vi89f/

If anyone could guide me with this. Thanks.

Comment: You should check out that "Text" tab. If you still don't find out anything, post the XML.

Comment: please edit your question with menu xml file.

Comment: Are you using custom widgets ? If so they might be not shown during preview but appears on runtime.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, stack won´t let me add more links to main post. Here are the two XML file.s                                                                                            Here is the Menu XML: 
[https://mega.co.nz/#!oRYB3ZBb!VXrckkaIde6tIUaLFI80s1-5Wv62o6jrLGjCIYPkhZg][3]

Here is Activity XML:
[https://mega.co.nz/#!4MxQQTLb!6toqQyxe6BQr5K2XUhzc8txXlpH9UttLQXCyTBCrmBo][4]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I interpret your question correctly , you want to add menu items in the action bar ?
In menu.xml, add the attribute

```
android:icon="@drawable/your_image"
```

to the menu item that you wish to show in the action bar.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If you see the app screenshot, there are 4 main menu red icons. Gallery, Menu, Information and Contact. I would like to change one of them, but I can´t find the image file to replace it.

Comment: If you have imported it into your IDE, it should be in one of the drawable folders. If not then you have to import it first.

Comment: I have gone through every single folder in drawables and the icons are not there, yet when I create an apk build, the icons appear on the app. Under the other comments below my first post, I have uploaded the xml files if that can help.

Comment: It seems you are using a library to get the icons like app:icon="...". This way you don't need to have the drawables in your folder as they are being imported directly from the ones in the library https://github.com/theDazzler/droidicon. You need to go through the docs of the library to see the image destination.

Comment: The icons are actually located here : https://github.com/theDazzler/droidicon/tree/master/droidicon/src/main/res/raw

Comment: Then please accept the answer, so others may be helped by it in the future